# What do you think about NResponder?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, signals, nresponder

I was on the point of start using AS3 Signals for my new project because Native Events has a bad reputation, and then I found this:
http://code.google.com/p/nineveh-responder/

But I couldn't find more information (in addition to official docs and tuts).
What do you think about NResponder?

OT: I can't create the tag "NResponder" in this question because is new :(

Comment: RE OT: I just added the tag for you. I'm not familiar with NResponder myself so I can't say much about it, but will try to take a look at it.

Comment: I see videos on this channel http://vimeo.com/user4498519, but has anyone ran any sort of performance tests on it?

Answer (score 0):

NResponder goes above and beyond the call of duty. It is soo easy to use and learn. The real difference maker is its *NResponder.remove(action,function,target)* method.

It has the ability to remove all event listeners that fall under the parameters provided. In one call, you can remove all listeners associated to one object(target), any listeners associated to a certain function, listeners that respond to a certain event like MouseEvent.CLICK, or any combination of these parameters.

Comment: These are good features. I'm curious to see how they are implemented. This type of 'access from any direction' can be tricky to implement _efficiently_.